# Sphinx search - newbie

Tags: php, sphinx

I have managed to get Sphinx running to index a table with the following:
emp_id, emp_name, emp_department, emp_gender, emp_join_date, emp_notes

How do I use Sphinx to return results where emp_gender is "male"?

```
<?php
include ('sphinxapi.php');
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SetServer( "SPHINX2", 3312 );
$cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$result = $cl->Query( "male","sphinx_search");
?>
```

The above returns male anywhere including the emp_notes field and emp_gender field. Please advice on how I can target columns. Will something like @emp_gender male work? It does not return results as expected

Comment: php has sphinx pecl extension. IMHO - it's faster than .php api wrapper. http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [field search operator](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/extended-syntax.html) like this:

```
$cl->Query( "@emp_gender male", "sphinx_search" );
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but 
$cl->Query( "@emp_gender male", "sphinx_search" );
and
$cl->Query( "male", "sphinx_search" );
return same set of results.. Is there anything I have to do in the config?

Answer (score 1):

Such information as gender better to store in attributes.
Your could change your SQL query to smth. like this:

```
select if(emp_getnder = 'male', 1, 0) as gender,.....
```

Then you may use 'gender' field as integer attribuite:

```
sql_attr_uint = gender
```

In your appp:

```
$cl->setFilter('gender', array(1)); //select only male
$cl->Query("", "sphinx_search");
```

this solution would work much faster then filter by field and it is much flexible, because
filters and queries are separated.